# How to mix raw SQL and non-raw with Laravel's fluent query builder

Tags: fluent, laravel, eloquent

I'm sure it's very simple but I couldn't find any examples.

I am using fluent in my Laravel application to log my users' logins and so I have created my own auth driver, however I am having a problem with a fluent query that mixes raw data and none raw, look at the following:

```
DB::table('logins')->insert(array(
    'login_email' => $arguments['email'],
    'login_date' => DB::raw('UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())'),
    'login_ip'=> DB::raw('INET_ATON('.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].')'),
    'login_result' => (bool)$success
));
```

which causes:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@gmail.com, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()), INET_ATON(127.0.0.1), ?)' at line 1

SQL: INSERT INTO `cs_logins` (`login_email`, `login_date`, `login_ip`, `login_result`) VALUES (?, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()), INET_ATON(127.0.0.1), ?)

Bindings: array (
  0 => false,
)
```

so I did the following:

```
DB::table('logins')->insert(array(
    'login_email' => DB::raw("'".$arguments['email']."'"),
    'login_date' => DB::raw('UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())'),
    'login_ip'=> DB::raw('INET_ATON('.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].')'),
'login_result' => DB::raw((bool)$success)
));
```

But as Dayle Rees says, if it looks ugly it's not in the framework... so I want to know what I am missing here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Use eloquent

First of all, if not already done, create a model for *Login*, so you can use laravel's own ORM **eloquent**. Eloquent allows you to write simple and yet powerful queries in a very expressive way.

Now you can do one of these two options:

```php
$logins = Login::create(array('email' => 'example@gmail.com'));
```

or, maybe more elegant in your case:

```php
$login = new Login;

$login->email = 'example@gmail.com';
$login->login_date = DB::raw('UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())');

$login->save();
```

See the **[eloquent docs](http://laravel.com/docs/database/eloquent#save)** for more information.

Comment: +1 tnx for the info, I bought and read Dayle Rees's tutorial and I decided Fluent seemed easier to start with, I think mainly because he used more Fluent examples and also showed how they work with Pivot tables so easily. Do you think eloquent is the way to go? Does eloquent have the same easy syntax to retrieve, update, delete multiple tables with several joins so easily?

Comment: btw I created a auth driver in my library folder how do I access my login model from the library, my login model is Login and extends Eloquent.

Comment: Eloquent is definitely the way to go. It has the same, easy synthax for all operations. Most of the operations are equal to fluent. `User::where_name('simon')->order_by('last_name')->get()` ist how you retrieve data using eloquent. The only real difference is `User::`, otherwise it looks pretty similiar, right? :) Check the docs for more info, it's rather easy to learn.

Comment: Laravel has an autoloader for files in the library folder. Name the file Classname.php und create the auth class accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

OK, never mind it seems like the "?" question mark just meant that fluent had not got to that part of creating the prepared statement. I am new to Laravel and Fluent and I thought the question mark meant the error was in that part of the query.

Comment: Thats right, a question mark means that param is missing/wrong. Did it solve the question?